# joining a table to itself which has no key

Tags: sql, join

I have a table like this:

```
Id-------Product---------date-------productID
1                a       2012             a1
1                a       2013             a1
1                b       2013             b1
2                a       2011             a1
2                c       2012             c1
```

It has almost 2 million row with no primary key.
I want to create a view which shows the number of products purchased by each customer. What should I do?  Thank u Guys!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks Man! i posted this question with my tablet, site is much different on tablet and i couldn't edit it

Comment: How do you identify a customer and an order, can you add the structure of the supporting tables to your question?

Comment: So what are the desired results for that example data? Why do you think it needs a self join rather than a simple group by?

Comment: @swestfall customers are identified by customerID which is shown in the above table as ID, there are a couple of other columns in the real table like the period of using product by customers and things like this. but there aren't actually any supporting tables. that's all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that `id` refers to the customer.  In that case, you don't want a `join`, you want a `group by`:

```
select id, count(*) as numPurchases, count(distinct product) as numProducts
from table t
group by id;
```

For a view, you just prepend with `create view t as`

Comment: why did you count distinct products? they might have bought the same product twice or more. the problem is i don't have an OrderID in the table

Comment: @RmanEdv . . . The statement:  "shows the number of products purchased " could mean the number of distinct products or the total number of purchases.  I included both.